# Django Need Help Re-writing Search/Filter Form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Original Code Without Forms.py: https://dpaste.org/jAi2

Here is what it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdMjE.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG6Jd.jpg

I want to completely re-write this code to use forms.py and an updated models.py. There is also the options of using forms.Form, forms.ModelForm, django-filters, django-select2, modelmultiplechoicefield, modelchoicefield but not sure what the best approach is.

There are a few things I want to accomplish:

1) Form validation

2) Instead of SSHing into the server to manually update the HTML subjects dropdown menu choices and the SUBJECT_CHOICES from models.py each time I want to add a new subject, I want to be able to update the subjects by adding/removing them from 127.0.0.1:8000/admin. I need a deduped list of subjects to be populated in the subjects dropdown menu in alphabetical order possibly with a template for loop or another method.

3) Courses can have many subjects (not just one) - (example Apple could be both a technology and a business subject). The template for loop needs to show all the subjects for each course individually. E.g. Course Apple will show Business and Technology as the subjects.

I started writing the code for the form but have not had much success.

What I have tried:

https://dpaste.org/yQ4S

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably don't want to use `dpaste.de` for your code snippets: they will expire in a few days. Use something persistent, or put the pertinent parts in as code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

1) You still want to use form validation, even on GET requests. Any time you are dealing with user input, you must validate it.

2) If you store the choices in a model, then you can dynamically update the choices *automatically* by having the choice field pull those choices from a queryset of that model. Just make sure it's done in a method, not in the top level of a module (that would only be executed when the server process starts).

3) You can use `<optgroup>` elements to group options in a `<select>` element. I'm not sure if there is something that handles this automatically if you pass a correctly-formed list to a `ChoiceField()`, but you could have custom widget rendering to handle that.